# Adding jQuery event handlers to pseudo selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have change the style for custom select box, even changed the arrow with css :after property.

Now my problem is when ever i clicked on down arrow drop down is not opening. Its correct because its on top of select box. How i can make it work so when user click on down arrow dropdown should open.

**HTML**

```
<div class="select-holder select-wrap poRel col-xs-4 col-sm-4 cntry-drop-down is-valid">
  <select class="select-item validate-me p-normal-text is-valid" data-validation-type="select_validation" id="ship_country" name="ship_country" data-default-msg="Country" autocomplete="off" tabindex="3">
    <option class="p-normal-text default-selected-value" value="" selected="selected">Country</option>
    <option class="p-normal-text" value="US" selected="">USA</option>
    <option class="p-normal-text" value="AU">Australia</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**CSS** - used to place the arrow besides the `select` element

```
.select-holder:after {
    top: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(100% - 50px);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: "\e259";
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Working [Demo here](http://codepen.io/saorabhkr/pen/YyGBbG).

How can I bind a click event on arrow, so it will open the select box.

Comment: You can't bind a click to a pseudo element (not with JS anyway, *maybe* there's a CSS hack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS below:

```
.select-holder:after {
  pointer-events: none;
  /* the rest of your code */
}
```

It will prevent the click events on the arrow, so it will bubble to the parent, making it work as you want.

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGRJKM)

Comment: I was aware about pointer-events: none, but didn't think on this way. very good work around.